# RSS Events Calendar

Tags: feeds

I installed 'Calendar' module in Drupal 7. What I want to know is if it's possible to get an RSS feed and feed that to the Calendar ?

I do realize that the 'Feeds' module will break it down and store it in the database, but was wondering if there is a more direct approach to displaying the RSS on the calendar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) - Requires **Views** and the Date API (packaged with the Date module).
- Views - support natively [RSS Feeds](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/creating-rss-feeds-in-drupal-using-views/).

So you need just add Feed display.

For importing events to calendar, you can use [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module, on source side there's some date(s) provided.

Comment: Hi Nikit, thank you for your answer. Was wondering can the Calendar receive those events through Views which supports RSS feeds? I just dont know how to connect them both.

Comment: Answer changed due to comment.

Comment: Hi Nikit, when you say on source side there's some date's provided, how do you mean? thx

Comment: Usually any date information there should be. If no date, then you can just use Feed item date.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that Events aren't really supported well in RSS, i.e. there isn't a place to provide start and end times. There was a draft spec made for RSS events (http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/event/), but It's not natively supported in Drupal. You would be better off setting up a generic XML or JSON feed that exposes the fields you need.